# Do i use count(*) to count record or i add count column into my table directly

Tags: mysql, sql

My team lead insisting me to add days entry count column within table and update it regularly. something like this

1. Get previous record
2. take count column value
3. Add .5 into that value
4. And update the count record in current record

like this

- .5
- 1
- 1.5
- 2 //each time i have to get previous value to make new value which means select statment, then update statement

While I think that this is not the right way. I can count [using Count(*)] the record to display days which is easy why i bother to add it, use update command to know previous entry etc. The reason he told that we can get count directly without query bunch of records which is performance wise is fast. How you do this? what is correct way?

Comment: Edit your question and provide (1) sample data; (2) desired results in a tabular format; (3) a tag for the database you are using.  Someone with your reputation should know how to ask and format a question.

Comment: More worringly than your questions, what happens if a record gets deleted?

Comment: If you guarantee that this value is equal or calculable from count of records and will always be, then I wouldn't store it since it adds too much complexity to logic, worsens supportability and may create some problems in future. Afaik, performance should not be an issue for indexed data.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev that why asked this question, what kind of complexity it will add

Comment: @doctorlove now we are not going to delete record from middle! we delete latest record but not from middle.

Comment: Perhaps do what you've been told, and have another version of the db which uses a function to report this and compare performance for a chat over a coffee another day?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you just want `row_number()` divided by 2:

```
select t.*,
       (row_number() over (order by ??) ) / 2.0
from t;
```

The `??` is for whatever column specifies the ordering of the table that you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE YourTable 
   SET COUNT_COLUMN = (SELECT MAX(COUNT_COLUMN) + 0.5 
                         FROM YourTable
                       )
 WHERE "Your condition for the current record";
```

For better performance add index on to COUNT_COLUMN column of YourTable.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi Fizan,**

You can achieve this using function. You can create a function to get resultant value and update it in you column. Like this -

```
CREATE function Get_Value_ToBeUpdated
RETURN DECIMAL(10,2)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE result decimal (10,2);
    DECLARE previousValue decimal (10,2);
    DECLARE totalCount int;

    SELECT previousValue = SELECT MAX(columnName) FROM YourTable order by primaryColumn desc
    SELECT totalCount    = SELECT COUNT(1) FROM YourTable

    SET result = ISNULL(previousValue,0) + ISNULL(totalCount,0)

    RETURN result;
END

UPDATE YourTable SET COLUMNNAME  = DBO.Get_Value_ToBeUpdated() WHERE Your condition
```

Thanks :)